# Arctic fox android app crashes on launch - React Native

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I have create react native project and trying writing native modules code using android studio.

Before that everything was smooth, up and running. Then was an update for android studio and I have upgraded it to arctic fox.

After that application start crashing without any reason, but gradle sync is happening properly.

I am using java 11.0.11 version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, for me to resolve and potentially for other people in the future...

1. Go to AVD manager
2. Remove the current device emulators
3. Rebuild emulators with selected versions

Let me know if this also works for others.